# Jmeter Calculate Value Response Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

how to jmeter calculate response data value

**example**

Number of thread = 3

Ramp Up = 1

Loop Count = 1

Thread 1 value extract = 3

Thread 2 value extract = 7

Thread 3 value extract = 10

**how to get total = 3+7+10 = 20**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the extractor and put the following code where

   ```
   props.put('value_' + ctx.getThreadNum(), vars.get('extracted_value'))
   ```
2. Then somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) you can use the following expression to get the sum of all values of properties which start with `value_`

   ```
   props.entrySet().findAll {prop -> prop.getKey().startsWith('value_')}.collect {prop -> prop.getValue() as int}.sum()
   ```

More information about what do these `props`, `ctx` and `vars` mean: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: thanks sir its work , can u help me to explain code number 2 , i need to learn how this code work